# Two first order non-linear differential equation: Using DSolve to obtain the solutions analytically

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, symbolic, nonlinear

I have two simple first order (coupled) differential equations which I denote as `system` together with its initial conditions

```
system = {A1'[x] == (j1/2)*A1[x]^2*Conjugate[A1[x]] + j1*A1[x]*A2[x]*Conjugate[A2[x]],
          A2'[x] == (j2/2)*A2[x]^2*Conjugate[A2[x]] + j2*A1[x]*A2[x]*Conjugate[A1[x]],
          A1[0] == √[P10], A2[0] == √[P20];
```

where `j1, j2, P10, P20` are all constants and independent of `x`. I then do

```
DSolve[system,{A1,A2},x]
```

And I'm returned with: `There are fewer dependent variables than equations, so the system is overdetermined`. But I have exactly 2 equations with 2 unknowns, so I'm not sure why Mathematica is returning this error. What am I doing wrong here?

Thank you.

Comment: Is `\Sqrt` a typo or you really write this in your code?

Comment: Which variables and constants, if any, are complex?  Do you have reason to suppose that analytical solutions actually exist?  `DSolve` is unable to find a solution, although it does not generate an error message for me.

Comment: Try quitting the kernel and then retry your code.

Comment: `\Sqrt` is a typo, but I didn't type that wrong in my code @xzczd

Comment: I mentioned `j1`, `j2`, `P10` and `P20` are constants @bbgodfrey An analytical solution should exist given that it represents the pump amplitude of a physical system. Even if it doesn't it should return something that says unable to find solution. Not what im getting.

Also quitting the kernel didn't change anything

Comment: I agree that `DSolve` should respond with an informative message when it does not find a solution.  Unfortunately it does not.  Also, many physical problems do not have analytical solutions.

Answer (score 4):

Amazingly, this `system` can be solved symbolically, at least for `j2 = j1`.  How useful the answer may be is a different issue.  If all symbols are real, then `system` (without initial conditions) can be rewritten as

```
system = {p1'[x] == j1 p1[x]^2 + 2 j1 p1[x] p2[x], 
          p2'[x] == 2 j2 p1[x] p2[x] + j2 p2[x]^2}
```

where `p1[x] = A1[x]^2` and `p2[x] = A2[x]^2`.  (If the symbols are complex, then `p1[x] = A1[x]*Conjugate[A1[x]]`, `p2[x] = A2[x]*Conjugate[A2[x]]`, and `j1` and `j2` replaced by their real parts.)  The obvious next step, `DSolve[system /. j2 -> j1, {p1, p2}, x]` returns unevaluated with [unexpected error messages](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/229818/1063).  So, instead, eliminate `p2`, which is straightforward.

```
D[Simplify[#/p1[x]], x] & /@ First[system];
% /. Rule @@ Last[system];
Solve[First[system], p2[x]] // Flatten;
eq = Simplify[%% /. %]
(* 3 j1 j2 p1[x]^3 + 2 p1''[x] == 
   2 (j1 + j2) p1[x] p1'[x] + ((2 j1 + j2) p1'[x]^2)/(j1 p1[x]) *)
```

which can be solved.

```
s = DSolve[eq /. j2 -> j1, b1[x], x][[1, 1]]
(* p1[x] -> InverseFunction[Inactive[Integrate][4/(3 (4 j1 K[1]^2 + 
   (E^((3 C[1])/8) j1^2 K[1]^3)/(4 E^((3 C[1])/8) j1^3 K[1]^5 + 
   Sqrt[-E^(((9 C[1])/8)) j1^6 K[1]^9 + 16 E^((3 C[1])/4) j1^6 K[1]^10])^(1/3) + 
   (4 E^((3 C[1])/8) j1^3 K[1]^5 + Sqrt[-E^(((9 C[1])/8)) j1^6 K[1]^9 + 
   16 E^((3 C[1])/4) j1^6 K[1]^10])^(1/3))), {K[1], 1, #1}] &][x + C[2]] *)
```

Perhaps, more convenient is

```
s[[2, 1]] - C[2] -> s[[2, 0, 1]][s[[1]]] - C[2];
% /. {K[1], 1, p1[x]} -> {K[1], p10, p1[x]} /. C[2] -> 0
(* x -> Inactive[Integrate][4/(3 (4 j1 K[1]^2 + 
   (E^((3 C[1])/8) j1^2 K[1]^3)/(4 E^((3 C[1])/8) j1^3 K[1]^5 + 
   Sqrt[-E^(((9 C[1])/8)) j1^6 K[1]^9 + 16 E^((3 C[1])/4) j1^6 K[1]^10])^(1/3) + 
   (4 E^((3 C[1])/8) j1^3 K[1]^5 + Sqrt[-E^(((9 C[1])/8)) j1^6 K[1]^9 + 
   16 E^((3 C[1])/4) j1^6 K[1]^10])^(1/3))), {K[1], p10, p1[x]}] *)
```

`p2` then can be determined by inserting the `p1`solution into `system[[1]]`, and the initial condition `p20` applied to obtain `C[1]`.  If `j2!= j1`, `DSolve` returns unevaluated.

**Addendum: Obtaining first integral**

`C[1]` can be derived more simply by obtaining a first integral of `eq` by the standard transformation valid for autonomous second order ODEs.  Doing so provides some useful insight as well.

```
eqv = eq /. {p1''[x] -> v'[z] v[z], p1'[x] -> v[z], p1[x] -> z}
(* 3 j1 j2 z^3 + 2 v[z] v'[z] == (j1 + j2) z v[z] + ((2 j1 + j2) v[z]^2)/(j1 z) *)

eqc1 = (DSolve[eqv, v[z], z] // First // Simplify) /. {v[z] -> p1'[x], z -> p1[x]}
(* (1/(3 j2)) 2 (j1 + j2)^2 (Log[p1[x]]/j1 + 
   (Log[(2 (j1 + j2) (j1 p1[x]^2 - p1'[x]))/(j1 p1[x]^2)] - (3 j2 
   Log[-((2 (j1 + j2) (3 j1 j2 p1[x]^2 + (-2 j1 + j2) p1'[x]))/(3 j1 j2 p1[x]^2))])
   /(2 j1 - j2))/(j1 - 2 j2)) == C[1] *)
```

from which `C[1]` is obtained by setting `x == 0` and applying initial conditions.  To obtain the complete solution for `p1[x]` requires solving  `eqc1` for `p1'[x]`, which can be done for `j2 = j1` and, perhaps, a few other cases. (This explains why `DSolve[eq, b1[x], x]` is unable to obtain solutions for arbitrary choices of `j2/j1`.)  So, consider `j2 = j1`.

```
Simplify[eqc1 /. {p1'[x] -> j1 p10^2 + 2 j1 p10  p20, p1[x] -> p10}]
Simplify[% /. j2 -> j1]
Exp[3/8 #] & /@ %
(* -((64 j1^2 (-p10 + p20)^3)/(27 p10 p20)) == E^((3 C[1])/8) *)
```

This procedure also provides a simple evaluation of `p2[x]`.  Interchange `p1[x]` and `p2[x]`, and `p10` and `p20` in the code block just before this addendum and also in the expression for `C[1]` just above.