# DSolve leaks internal error messages when attempting to solve two first order autonomous ODEs

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, bugs, symbolic, nonlinear

**Issue reported to Wolfram, Inc as a possible bug in Version 12.1.1; CASE:4630268.**

With Mathematica "12.1.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 19, 2020)", `DSolve` produces unexpected error messages:

```
 DSolve[{p1'[x] == p1[x]^2 + 2 p1[x] p2[x], 
         p2'[x] == 2 p1[x] p2[x] + p2[x]^2}, {p1, p2}, x]
```

> > Union::normal: Nonatomic expression expected at position 2 in { ... }⋃$Failed.

> > Flatten::normal: Nonatomic expression expected at position 1 in Flatten[$Failed].

and returns unevaluated after a few minutes. Evidently, `DSolve` has passed the bad argument `{...}⋃$Failed` to `Union`.  I am asking

- Is this a bug?  (I think it is, because `DSolve` should not show internal error messages to the user.)
- Is there a work-around?  ([This system is solvable, when converted to a single second-order ODE](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/229712/1063), so the pair of first-order ODEs also should be solvable.)

**Update: Issue resolved in Mathematica "12.3.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 19, 2021)"**

This bug has been eliminated in the sense that the internal errors no longer are leaked.  Instead, `DSolve` simply returns unevaluated after a few minutes.

Comment: With v12.1.1 on a Mac I see two internal errors `Union::normal` and `Flatten::normal`

Comment: @BobHanlon  Upon further consideration, I added the second error.  Thanks for the recommendation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does this count as a workaround?:

```
(* dividing 2nd ODE by 1st yields a homogeneous ODE *)
p2sol = DSolve[
     {p2'[p1] == (2 p1 p2[p1] + p2[p1]^2) /
                  (p1^2 + 2 p1 p2[p1])}, p2, p1] /.
    C[1] -> Log[C[1]] /. 
   p_Power :> RuleCondition[p, True];

(* p2sol turns the p1'[x] ODE in the system into a separable equation *)
PrintTemporary@Dynamic[foo = Clock[Infinity]];
TimeConstrained[
   (Print[foo]; #) &@
    Flatten@ DSolve[#, p2, x],
   30,
   Print[Style[foo, Red]]; $Failed] & /@
 (Last[system] /. p1[x] -> p1[p2[x]] /. p2sol)
```

> ```
> (*
> 3.30611
> 33.329
> 63.273
> {{p1 -> Function[{x}, 
>     InverseFunction[
>       Inactive[
>          Integrate][(-9 C[1] K[1]^2 + 
>           Sqrt[3] Sqrt[C[1]^2 K[1]^3 (4 C[1] + 27 K[1])])^(1/3)/(
>         K[1] (-2 2^(1/3) 3^(2/3) C[1] K[1] + 
>            9 K[1] (-9 C[1] K[1]^2 + 
>               Sqrt[3] Sqrt[C[1]^2 K[1]^3 (4 C[1] + 27 K[1])])^(1/3) + 
>            2^(2/3) 3^(
>             1/3) (-9 C[1] K[1]^2 + 
>               Sqrt[3] Sqrt[C[1]^2 K[1]^3 (4 C[1] + 27 K[1])])^(
>             2/3))), {K[1], 1, #1}] &][
>      x/3 + C[2]]]}, $Failed, $Failed}
> *)
> ```

One can combine with with `p2sol` to obtain `p2'[x]`.  The solutions *can* be stated as implicit equations, but *Mathematica* tries really hard to solve them.

Note this system and [the one it came from](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/229712/1063) admit two one-parameter families of symmetries, scalings `{p1, p2, 1/x} -> C[1] {p1, p2, 1/x}` and translations `x -> x + C[2]`. Thus they can theoretically be expressed as successive quadratures as above, provided one can solve the intermediate equations such as the one produced by this generalization:

```
DSolve[
  {p2'[p1] == (2 a p1 p2[p1] + b p2[p1]^2)/(c p1^2 + 2 d p1 p2[p1])}, 
  p2, p1]

(*
Solve[(-c (b - 2 d) Log[p2[p1]/p1] +
   (b c - 4 a d) Log[-2 a + c - (b p2[p1])/p1 + (2 d p2[p1])/ p1]) / 
  ((2 a - c) (b - 2 d)) == C[1] - Log[p1], p2[p1]]
*)
```

Comment: Very nice answer (+1),  A few questions: `x -> x + C[2]` is essential to reducing the second order system to first order.  What advantage does `{p1, p2} -> C[1] {p1, p2}` (actually, `{p1, p2, 1/x} -> C[1] {p1, p2, 1/x}`, I believe) provide?  Where is `RuleCondition` documented, and what does `/. p_Power :> RuleCondition[p, True]` do in the code above?  Should the undefined symbol `p1sol` actually be `p2sol`?

Comment: The scaling symmetry means it's reducible to a homogeneous ODE; the translation symmetry means it's autonomous, and autonomous first-order ODEs, which you get after the first integration, are separable.  `RuleCondition` can be found only on site; look at the oldest posts; I think @WReach explains it. I used it for in-place simplification inside `Function`, which is `HoldAll`. All it does is evaluate and replace the `Power[E, Log[C[1]]` that comes from the previous substitution inside `Function`. The power evaluates to `C[1]`, which looks much nicer. It's not important, though.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Yeah, `p1sol` should be `p2sol`.  I solved it both ways, but it made little difference.  And then I changed the fancy monitoring code and forgot to change the p1 back to p2.

Comment: @bbgodfrey My computer was crashing...I think my first comment was too hasty: It becomes homogeneous because of both symmetries. The system being autonomous, which is necessary to reduce the system to a single ODE, led me to ignore `x` or `1/x` as you cleverly formulated the transformation.  Scalings and homogeneity go hand-in-hand, and the single ODE obtained being homogeneous is connected to the scaling symmetry.