# DSolve returns no results for two simple non-linear ODE

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

I have the following two first order non-linear DEs that I denote as `system`

```
system = {A1'[x] == I*α11/2*A1[x]*Abs[A1[x]]^2 + I*α11*A1[x]*Abs[A2[x]]^2, A2'[x] == I*α22*A2[x]*Abs[A1[x]]^2 + I*α22/2*A2[x]*Abs[A2[x]]^2, A1[0] == Sqrt[P10], A2[0] == Sqrt[P20]};
```

where `P10, P20` are the initial conditions (real and independent of `x`) and `α11, α22` are real parameters that are independent of `x`. I proceed to solve them with

```
DSolve[system, {A1, A2}, {x}]
```

but I'm returned with

```
(*DSolve[{Derivative[1][A1][x] == 1/2 I α11 A1[x] Abs[A1[x]]^2 + I α11 A1[x] Abs[A2[x]]^2, Derivative[1][A2][x] == I α22 A2[x] Abs[A1[x]]^2 + 1/2 I α22 A2[x] Abs[A2[x]]^2, A1[0] == Sqrt[P10], A2[0] == Sqrt[P20]}, {A1, A2}, {x}]*)
```

which is pretty much the same thing as my `system`. In other words, Mathematica isn't solving it at all and is regurgitating `system`, yet it doesn't return as an error or warning. Furthermore I'm surprise that DSolve is unable to solve relatively simple systems of ODEs. I am confident that an analytical solution exists as these corresponds to pump amplitudes equations for travelling waves.

Comment: Maple also fails with it, returning `NULL`.

Comment: Did you check `system` numerically with `NDSolve`? What are approbriate parameter values (examplary)?

Comment: My perspective on "simple": (1) I'd say the only simple nonlinear ODE is one that is separable, or can be transformed into separable. (2) I wouldn't say `Abs[z]` is a particularly simple function.  Here's a separable ODE that doesn't have a closed-form solution: `DSolve[z'[t] == I*Abs[z[t]], z, t]`.  The returned solution is problematic because the integral is not path-independent. (Compare `NIntegrate[1/Abs[z], {z, 1, I}]` and `NIntegrate[1/Abs[z], {z, 1, 2 + I, I}]`.)

Comment: From the "Possible Issues" section of the documentation for [`Abs`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Abs.html), "Abs is a function of a complex variable and is therefore not differentiable" and "In particular, the limit that defines the derivative is direction dependent and therefore does not exist" Consequently, the presence of `Abs` in a differential equation is problematic.

Comment: The answer to [229656](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/229712/1063) that I derived for you last week may be of value here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my answer to [229656](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/229712/1063), the solution is

```
s = {A1 -> Function[{x}, Sqrt[P10] Exp[I α11 x (P10/2 + P20)]], 
     A2 -> Function[{x}, Sqrt[P20] Exp[I α22 x (P20/2 + P10)]]}
```

as can be demonstrated by

```
Simplify[system /. s, P10 > 0 && P20 > 0 && (α11 | α22 | x) ∈ Reals]
(* {True, True, True, True} *)
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I was going to address that I've solved it on my own mathematically (without Mathematica) based on some references (https://sci-hub.tw/https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/B9780128170427000178 page 405, equation 10.2.8). Nonetheless, this is the correct answer.